# Use proxy to connect to a mysql db through PDO

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, proxy

I'm trying to connect to a remote mysql database with PHP PDO (php version 5.3)
and I need it to go through a proxy.

My connection looks like this right now.

```
$ldb = new PDO("mysql:dbname=users;host=my.remote.host.com", username, password);
```

I'dd need it to go through a proxy, like http://proxy.mydomain.com:port

I've searched through the PDO Doc and can't seem to find anything on the subject. Is there a way to do it, or am I way off?

Thanks

Comment: This is possible.  Out of interest, why do you wish to do this? The answer to that may affect people's answers. My answer would be: you can use SSH tunnelling - just get yourself a VPS to act as a proxy. This approach will encrypt the traffic for you as well.

Comment: After some reading, I quickly realized that mysql through PDO isn't using the http protocol, and therefore, should not be affected by an http proxy. My problem was somewhere else.

Comment: Even if not by the proxy, a connection could be affected by e.g. a firewall or similar. So @halfer answer is the one I am also usingto get through a firewall

Comment: If you have an answer to the original question @Markus, I am sure people would be interested (even though it looks like the OP had a different problem in the end). Do you have any config stuff to offer for people who wish to tunnel their MySQL connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly PDO related, but you can tunnel the connection through SSH. Additionally, this offers encryption for your connection. This is especially helpful for getting through proxy or even firewall blocking port 3306. You would then connect to the tunnelled port on localhost.

I am doing this via PuTTY. There are couple of tutorials out there on how to achieve a port tunneling, e.g. [from the Kettering University](https://my.kettering.edu/offices-administration/information-technology/networks-security-storage/remote-desktop/remote) (for mysql it is port 3306 instead of the port 3389 mentioned in this tutorial but the rest is the same)

Answer (score 1):

Complementing Markus answer, here the steps you can follow to tunnel a port through ssh using command line:

```
ssh -L local_port:database_ip_inside_remote_network:remote_port user@server_with_connection_to_a_dabatase_you_need
```

example:

```
ssh -L 3306:10.109.36.4:3306 my_user@192.168.101.19
```

Now you can use `localhost` and the port `3306` inside your php script